# How to show default text if database property is empty in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a template. But I want to have some default text if property is empty.

I have it now like this:

Comment: Could you also provide your TS file?

Comment: I added with interface

Comment: Like... the way the current way you are doing this seems fine, try testing it by having the welcomePopupBody with no value and check if the HTML code is working. You will either have to change the validation or the way you are writing it.

Comment: I would change that *ngIf to - *ngIf="result.welcomePopupBody == null;then defaultTextBody else defaultTextBody"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using if else condition wrong way.
You have to use `*ngIf="result.welcomePopupBody === null; else textBlock"`
this way.

See below code.

```
<app-modal [modalTitle]="modalTitle" [modalId]="modalId" (closeModal)="close.emit(false)">
  <ng-container *ngIf="result; else loading">
    <div class="modal modal-first-view">
      <div *ngIf="result.welcomePopupBody === null; else textBlock" class="modal-text modal-text-first-view">
        <p>
          Welkom, mijn naam is <i class="italics">Roos</i>. Ik ben jouw Virtuele coach en ik ben er om je te te helpen.
        </p>
        <p>
          Als je op onderstaande knop klikt krijg je meer uitleg over je deelname en start je de vragenlijst.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="first-view-button-wrap">
        <button (click)="buttonClicked()" type="button" class="button button-double-shadow button-first-view">
             {{ result.welcomePopupButtonText }}
         </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-img modal-img-first-view first-view-lady">
        <img [src]="result.welcomePopupImage" alt="Nice lady here to help" />
      </div>

      <!--   <img [src]="result.welcomePopupImage" /> -->
    </div>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-template #textBlock>
    <div [innerHtml]="result.welcomePopupBody"></div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #loading>
    ...Loading
  </ng-template>
</app-modal>
```

Comment: ah, txh, but i only get on this line:   <ng-template #textBlock [innerHtml]="result.welcomePopupBody"></ng-template> error Property binding innHtml not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled co

Comment: Thank you. very nice

Answer (score 0):

You can directly write template for positive condition inside the div

```
<app-modal [modalTitle]="modalTitle" [modalId]="modalId" (closeModal)="close.emit(false)">
    <ng-container *ngIf="result; else loading">
        <div class="modal modal-first-view">

            <div *ngIf="result.welcomePopupBody === null; else textBlock" class="modal-text modal-text-first-view">
                <p>
                    Welkom, mijn naam is <i class="italics">Roos</i>. Ik ben jouw Virtuele coach en ik ben er om je te
                    te helpen.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Als je op onderstaande knop klikt krijg je meer uitleg over je deelname en start je de vragenlijst.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="first-view-button-wrap">
                <button (click)="buttonClicked()" type="button" class="button button-double-shadow button-first-view">
          {{ result.welcomePopupButtonText }}
        </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-img modal-img-first-view first-view-lady">
                <img [src]="result.welcomePopupImage" alt="Nice lady here to help" />
        </div>

                <!--   <img [src]="result.welcomePopupImage" /> -->
            </div>

    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #textBlock [innerHtml]="result.welcomePopupBody"></ng-template>
    <ng-template #loading>
        ...Loading
    </ng-template>
</app-modal>
```